# MySQL: calling a stored procedure from another, is it possible to send variables to the one I'm calling?

Tags: mysql, call, procedure

This is basically the stored procedure. Of course I synthesize avoiding `DELIMITER...`, `DROP IF EXISTS...`, `CREATE...`, `BEGIN...` and so on:

```
SELECT
    _flow.id,
    _flow.id_status,
    _flow_status.id,
    _flow_status.status

FROM
    flow _flow
    INNER JOIN flow_status _flow_status ON _flow_status.id = _flow.id_status;
```

What I really need is to call another stored procedure (`CALL another_sp (var_flow_id);`) SENDING TO IT in some way/variable the data contained in `_flow.id`.  I can't find the way and I have been looking around a lot.  Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is 3 general ways to transfer some value(s) into SP. 1st (preferred) - via SP parameters. 2nd (needed the execution in the same connection) - via user-defined variable(s) with predefined name(s). 3rd - via static service table (allows to transfer table-type data, when executing in the same connection then the table may be temporary). If you need to transfer the value received from the query then you may use 1st method and intermediate variable (using SELECT .. INTO) if this is single value (the query returns one row strictly, from cursor, etc.), else use 3rd method.

Comment: Thanks @Akina!  I'll try that.  I really appreciate your time.